# Wolfram Engine for Developers activation/licensing issues

Tags: installation, licensing

After getting my account I successfully installed the Windows version on Windows 10 and the linux version on Kubuntu 20.04 on a multiboot laptop. However when I tried to install the linux version on additional linux distros on the same laptop (Lubuntu 20.04, mx linux 19.2) doing exactly the same steps as before the installation fails complaining about a false activation key.

I'm not sure whether this is an intended behaviour (each engine download only be valid for installation on one machine/OS?) or a bug/issue with the installation. Can I use the my personal developer license on more than one machine and/or operating system installaton or am I restricted to one? If the former is the case how can I fix my installation issue on the other linux distributions?

Comment: This is better suited for Wolfram Support, unfortunately we can't give you much guidance here on licensing issues. Please contact them with the same query. (However if you are doing performance tests I'd be quite interested to hear if MX Linux really is that much more performant than Ubuntu)

Comment: I think there is a limit of two installations per Wolfram user ID.
I find that about an order of magnitude too low (after all people do want to experiment on various OS's, installations, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll check with support. I was posting it here because i was hoping it not being a license issue, but just an installation issue/bug that could be overcome.